# AJAX does not carry session variables

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a centralized index page that contains all of my pages. Inside this index page, I have my session started. I tested this by echoing out all variables, it works.

On the AJAX php script, I try to call a session variable, and it seem to print anything out: not even a session id. According to my research, you need to call session_start() on the AJAX script. I did so, and it starts the session, but with a different ID and no access to session variables set on the main website. I have not found anything on the first 5 pages of Google replicating my problem.

IF I change the **'".$_SESSION['usr']."'** part of the mysqli query to my username, it works. This is also proof that it is, in fact, the AJAX script not seeing the session variables.

What can I do get the AJAX script to see the session that is on the main website and not it's own session with no data?

Code:

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Moving North
    $('#moveNorth').on('click', function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/moveNorth.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {data : value},
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                 $('#coordinate-y').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Something went wrong. Please email an admin.");
            }
        });
     });
});
```

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php

$sessionTest = session_id();//$_SESSION['usr'];

echo "Session Test | " . $sessionTest . " |";

$mysqli = new mysqli("db_host", "db_user", "db_password", "db_name");

if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
else
{
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE table_name SET coord_x = coord_x - 1 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['usr']."'");
}

?>
```

**Page calling the AJAX:**

```
<?php
$sessionTestID = session_id();//$_SESSION['usr']; 
echo $sessionTestID;
?>
```

Comment: You might have an issue with the domain set for the cookie. Check php documentation for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Are you using session_start() on EVERY php page you ever go to?

Comment: @BertrandLefort This is how I am creating a cookie:  session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);

Comment: @Jonast92 Technically, yes, because they are all included into one central page. On the individual .php files, no. The session has never given me a problem until I needed the variables in an AJAX call.

Comment: I would put all my session management in a single php file, then reuse it across each script to see if it fix the issue

Comment: session_start() should be present in all pages that use the session.

Comment: small tutorial: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm

Comment: Inlcuding my session management file seemed to work. Thank you, @Bertrand!